# .SWF File is not showing in local html file

Tags: html, flash, embed

I have embed a swf file in the local html file but it is not showing the slideshow.

can anyone tell me what is the issue with following code.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" width="943" height="290">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<param name="src" value="http://www.unitedwayofgnb.org/imageRotator.swf">
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="943" height="290" src="http://www.unitedwayofgnb.org/imageRotator.swf" wmode="transparent">
</object>
```

Comment: Works for me, Chrome 31

Comment: Seriously...? Then why its not showing at my side.. Is it some issue with my current flash player?

Comment: I also have chrome 31 but not working here?

Comment: FWIW it also works for me with Firefox 25 & Flash 11.9.900 and IE10, same Flash version. I think there's something about your machine or environment that's causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you for confirming it again for me.. So its mean it will work fine on my clients machine.. Thanks again :)